# Stop function firing before I call it from Ternary to render html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ternary

I am trying to call a function conditionally from a ternary, however it seems to be calling the function before I am wanting it to...

I understand that usually I can get around this by doing `() => myFunc()`, however this doesn't seem to work and breaks my build.

```
const myFunc = () => {
    if (typeof someVar === 'boolean') {
            if (someVar) {
                return <h1>BOOLEAN - TRUE</h1>
            } else {
                return <Redirect to={`/my-page`} />
            }
        } else {
            return <h1>not boolean</h1>
        }
}

return !somethingLoaded
        ? <h1>not loaded yet</h1>
        : !extraThingLoaded
            ? <h1>Not quite finished</h1>
            : myFunc()
```

Running this code as it is, is calling the `<Redirect>` before anything can be done.

I did attempt

```
!extraThingLoaded
            ? <h1>Not quite finished</h1>
            : () => myFunc() // <-- Added this that usually works...
```

however I get the error: `Functions are not valid as a React child`

Also trying:

```
!extraThingLoaded
            ? <h1>Not quite finished</h1>
            : {myFunc()}
```

seems to expect a `{` after the function name

Comment: what is `x()` do?

Comment: Updated to be `myFunc()` now. Copy/paste laziness, sorry.

Comment: Can you please add a running codesandbox snippet? it will increase the chances of getting answers quicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
const renderThings = ()=>{
  if(somethingLoaded && extraThingLoaded){
    x();
  }else if(!somethingLoaded){
    return <h1>not loaded yet</h1>
  }else if(!extraThingLoaded){
    return <h1>Not quite finished</h1>
  }
}
return (<div>{renderThings()}</div>)
```